# .ajax POST image data URL not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, canvas

I have a canvas converted into a data url, and I need to save it locally in my server. For some reason I can't get this (simple) thing to work. It doesn't write any file on "natalisations" folder. The folder as the write permissions, and javascript seems to do it's work fine and with no errors. Php doesn't give me any error, just doesn't write the actual file.

**Javascript**

```
function postData(data) {
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uploadaux.php",
        data: {image: data}
    }).done(function( respond ) {
        alert(respond);
    });
```

the output of alert(data) is `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAg(...)"`

This is the uploadaux.php file:

```
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {    

    $dataURL = $_POST["image"];  

    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
    $data = $parts[1];  

    $data = base64_decode($data);  

    $fp = fopen('natalisations/image.jpg', 'w');  
    fwrite($fp, $data);  
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

I've been debugging this for ages... and no sign of finding a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please put all your `data` value to check and try to replicate?

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive, simply saying "It doesn't work" doesn't help at all.

Comment: "doesn't work" as in "doesn't right any file on "natalisations" folder.

the folder as the right permissions, and javascript seems to do it's work fine and with no errors. php doesn't give me any error, just doesn't write the actual file

Comment: data is way too big to post, is there any way I could show you it's value?

Comment: Go to http://pastebin.com/ and share the link @biip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Check your $_FILES[]

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zHmCtPvW

here is it

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was in posting data. Try outputting getcwd() to see if you use correct relative path to save your file.

Comment: it's fixed! the problem was file_put_contents needed the full path. no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that your javascript isn't returning anything to you, it's because you have no return data in your PHP, try this, it also has a fair bit of debugging.

```
if(isset($_POST['image']) && !empty($_POST['image'])) {    

    $dataURL = $_POST['image'];  

    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL); 
    $data = base64_decode($parts[1]);

    if(is_writable('natalisations/')) {    
        $success = file_put_contents('natalisations/image.jpg', $data);
        echo ($success ? 'success' : 'unable to save file');
    } else {
        echo 'directory not writable';
    }
} else {
    echo 'no image';
}
```

Comment: it echoes "directory not writable". i just did chmod 777 to the path

Comment: Likely because it needs the full path, ie `/home/username/public_html/natalisations/`

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot! is this file_put_contents default behaviour?

Comment: All write functions require 777 access

Comment: i mean the full path thing. i believe the directory was writeable all the time

Comment: That's how all the write functions work.